# Sql String Function

Tags: sql, string

Need help to do a simple task in sql string in my table there is a field comment(user comments).

In my procedure, I am passing a parameter `@input`.  I want to check whether the string contains the string @input, and if it contains @input then add some style to the substring(that same as @input).

eg: if the Comment string like - "i have added the user Test user"  and

```
@input - "tes"
```

I want the output as

```
i have added the user <span style="color:red">Tes</span>t user
```

Comment: For what database?  @ for variables is supported by SQL Server and MySQL.

Comment: Can you make your question more clearer? Something like create the result of table...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using T-SQL (Microsoft SQL)

```
SELECT REPLACE(comment, @input, '<span style="color:red">' + SUBSTRING(comment, PATINDEX('%' + @input + '%', comment), len(@input)) + '</span>') as cmt
FROM thetable
WHERE comment LIKE '%' + @input + '%'
```

EDIT: OK Even more ugly and still untested, but should work for you.  Now we are replaceing the exact text from the string back into the replace.

**UPDATE:** I just tested this code and it works as you need it to.  It finds `Tes` in the string using `'tes'` and outputs `Tes` as it is in the original string.

Comment: Hi , thanks....but problem is it will modify the actual string...eg..if the string "i have deleted the user 'Test user'"..this will produce and output -"i have deleted the user '<span style="color:red">'tes</span>t' user'"...here the name 'Test' changes to test....i think u understand my problem

Comment: The is the problem you deal with when you work with case insensitive collation.

Answer (score 1):

```
select comment from table where comment like '%' + @input + '%'
```

Irrespective of the RDBMS, there is `LIKE` in other RDBMS(SQLserver, Oracle, Mysql). Specifically my answer is assuming your DB is Sql server since I noticed the use of `@`

**EDIT:**
To get the `<span>` tag, I think you may have to use regex to replace the input string with `<span>` tag in the output result. Better would be to do it in the underlying code instead of getting results from SQL query with format.
In SQL server you can use `REPLACE` function too.

Comment: Where's the text updating?  Oracle doesn't support @ in a variable either.

Comment: thanks for reply,Sql server 2005 - but my problem is ,i got the all comments by using the s"elect comment from table where comment like @input" statements,but i want to modify the substring( like @input) in the string  as i explained in frist post

Comment: @OMG Ponies - Aaah.. The question is edited after my answer. Sorry, did not see the edit. The <span> tag was not visible in first version of question. Hence my answer.

Comment: This will only do an exact match to @input even though you used LIKE.  You need to add a wild card(s).